# DAG run won't start after being created using REST API

Tags: python, airflow

- I am using Python to kick of DAG runs using the Airflow (v1.10.1) REST API.
- The DAG runs appear to be created correctly because I can see them in the GUI as 'running'
- the execution date is set correctly to what I am passing in. However, all DAG nodes just remain in state "no status" and never start.
- Is there maybe another config item that I need to pass in? Currently I am only passing in execution date like so:

```
parameters = {'execution_date': '2019-02-06'}
raw_response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=parameters)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which version of Airflow you are using?

Comment: Is the scheduler running?

Comment: Please check Scheduler is running as @RyanTheCoder 's answer, and also check AF log. Sometime error happens and it is stuck.

Comment: I am using v1.10.1

Comment: Scheduler is running

Comment: ...or so I thought. Scheduler was in fact not running. I started it and that fixed it. Thank you!!

Comment: @RyanTheCoder Please add an answer as to what worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your Airflow scheduler is running as expected as one of its jobs is to trigger the task instances.